# How to connect multiple clients to one host via Wifi P2P

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm trying to create a WiFiP2P to communicate with 2 android phones and one Raspberry Pi. I want one phone as host and the second phone + Raspberry Pi as clients.

Until know i could create a test APP to connect the 2 phones via Wifi direct (tested successful). I was following a great tutorial on Youtube [Wifi P2P](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nw627o-8Fok&list=PLFh8wpMiEi88SIJ-PnJjDxktry4lgBtN3). Unfortunately the tutorial just show how to connect one host with one client and not multiple clients. 
I was trying to follow the Android developer [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct), but I have not enough experience to understand everything.
I hope you guys can help me to understand what I have to change in my code and explain me why.

The following code is the exact copy from the mentioned tutorial.

Here my MainActivity:

```java
package com.example.wifip2p;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDeviceList;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pGroup;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
    ListView listView;
    TextView read_msg_box, connectionStatus;
    EditText writeMsg;

    WifiManager wifiManager;

    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

    List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    String[] deviceNameArray;
    WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;

    static final int MESSAGE_READ=1;

    ServerClass serverClass;
    ClientClass clientClass;
    SendReceive sendReceive;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission is not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    1);
        }

        initialWork();
        exqListener();
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuff = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String tempMsg = new String(readBuff,0,msg.arg1);
                    read_msg_box.setText(tempMsg);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    private void exqListener() {
        btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    btnOnOff.setText("ON");
                    if(mManager!=null) {
                        mManager.removeGroup(mChannel, null);
                    }

                }else{
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    btnOnOff.setText("OFF");
                }
            }
        });

        btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Started");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        connectionStatus.setText("Discovery Starting Failed");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                final WifiP2pDevice device = deviceArray[i];
                WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;



               mManager.connect(mChannel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected to " + device.deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int reason) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String msg = writeMsg.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"MSG: " + msg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                sendReceive.write(msg.getBytes());
            }
        });
    }

    private void initialWork() {
        btnOnOff= findViewById(R.id.onOff);
        btnDiscover = findViewById(R.id.discover);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.peerListView);
        read_msg_box = findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
        connectionStatus = findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
        writeMsg = findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(),null);

        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    }



    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
                if(!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)){
                    peers.clear();
                    peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

                    deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                    deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
                    int index = 0;

                    for(WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()){
                        deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceAddress;
                        deviceArray[index] = device;
                        index++;
                    }

                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,deviceNameArray);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }

                if(peers.size()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Devices Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    };



    WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener connectionInfoListener = new WifiP2pManager.ConnectionInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
            final InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress;

            if(wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed && wifiP2pInfo.isGroupOwner){
                connectionStatus.setText("Host");
                serverClass=new ServerClass();
                serverClass.start();
            }else if(wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed){
                connectionStatus.setText("Client");
                clientClass = new ClientClass(groupOwnerAddress);
                clientClass.start();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver,mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            clientClass.socket.close();
            serverClass.serverSocket.close();
            serverClass.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        try {
            clientClass.socket.close();
            serverClass.serverSocket.close();
            serverClass.socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class ServerClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        ServerSocket serverSocket;

        @Override
        public void run() {
          //  serverSocket= null;
          //  socket = null;
            try {
                Log.i("ServerSocket is called", "Called");
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    private class SendReceive extends Thread{
        private Socket socket;
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private OutputStream outputStream;

        public SendReceive(Socket skt){
            socket = skt;
            try {
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            while(socket!=null){
                try {
                    bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
                    if(bytes > 0){
                        handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void write (byte[] bytes){
            try {
                outputStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClientClass extends Thread{
        Socket socket;
        String hostAdd;

        public ClientClass(InetAddress hostAddress){
            hostAdd = hostAddress.getHostAddress();
           // socket = null;
            socket = new Socket();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostAdd,8888),500);
                sendReceive = new SendReceive(socket);
                sendReceive.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my BroadcastReceiver Class:

```java
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;

    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, MainActivity mActivity)
    {
        this.mManager = mManager;
        this.mChannel = mChannel;
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,-1);

            if(state==WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED){
                Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi is ON",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Wifi is OFF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){

            if(mManager!=null){
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel,mActivity.peerListListener);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: P2P peers changed");
        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            if(mManager==null){
                return;
            }
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(networkInfo.isConnected()){
                mManager.requestConnectionInfo(mChannel,mActivity.connectionInfoListener);
            }else{
                mActivity.connectionStatus.setText("Device Disconnected");
            }

        }else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)){
            //do something
        }

    }
}
```